# how to check mac machine is busy with some taco build of cordova project on windows machine

Tags: macos, visual-studio, cordova, build, taco

My problem is that, I have 3 windows machines and 3 mac machines. I can make build on any mac machine using any windows machine using taco build command. Suppose Mac 1 machine is busy with windows 1 machine for making ios build. if windows 2 machine want to make build on mac 1 it should automatically switch on mac 2 or mac 3. Please let me know how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a great answer to this question.  Here's just some suggestions - a couple things to consider:

1. Load Balancers - if you have the infrastructure in place, you can setup a load balancer to front the multiple different mac build machines.  Then, point your windows machines to that load balancer.
2. Consider a third party solution like http://www.macincloud.com/.
3. Consider a third party build solution like using VSTS to build your source for IOS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/xcode/xcode-projects
4. Point your individual Windows machines to their own individual mac build machines.

Comment: Thanks for answer but all points are not suitable  for my requirement. I need taco configuration setting or some other logic.

Comment: You say you have 3 macs and 3 clients, why not pair them up 1:1?

Comment: Taco/remotebuild do not have load balancing built in. You can however check whether a machine is busy using appropriate http(s) requests from https://github.com/Microsoft/TACO/blob/master/src/taco-remote/RESTAPI.md#get-httplocalhost3000mountlocationbuildtasks